# Замена UNICODE символов в строке из файла?

Tags: c

Есть html файл, в котором записана простейшая текстовая информация на русском языке.
Нужно пробежаться по файлу и заменить в нём некоторые части слов.
Допустим в файле будет множество слов на "ЖИ/ШИ", но написанные через "ы".
Нужно пройтись пройтись по файлу и во всех нужных нам местах заменить "ы" на "и".
Вот наработка:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define LEN 1000

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    puts("'ЖИ' и 'ШИ' ПИШИ С БУКВОЙ 'И'!");

    wchar_t* cArray[LEN];
    wchar_t _check = L"", _checkNext = L"";

    FILE *_initialFile, *_correctedFile; 

    _wfopen_s(&_initialFile, L"initial.html", L"r,ccs=UNICODE");
    _wfopen_s(&_correctedFile, L"corrected.html", L"w,ccs=UNICODE");

    if (_initialFile == NULL)
    {
        puts("Исходный файл пуст!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (fgetws(cArray, LEN, _initialFile) != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < wcslen(cArray); i++) {
            _check = cArray[i];
            _checkNext = cArray[i + 1];
            if ((_check == L"Ж" && _checkNext == L"ы") || (_check == L"ж" && _checkNext == L"ы") || (_check == L"Ш" && _checkNext == L"ы") || (_check == L"ш" && _checkNext == L"ы")) {
                cArray[i + 1] = L"и";
                i=i+2;
            }
        }
        fwprintf_s(_correctedFile, L"%s", cArray);
    }

    fclose(_correctedFile);
    fclose(_initialFile);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Она прекрасно копирует исходный файл в новый, но не заменяет.
Я пытался выводить считанные символы и ставить точки между считанными символами.   Пришел к выводу, что **символы не считываются из строки совсем**.
Как исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего текст .html файла в кодировке UTF-8, а не в default кодировке RUS (что это у вас, cp1251?), поэтому корректного преобразования в Unicode не происходит.

Comment: Тогда как сделать правильно?

Comment: Исходный .html файл действительно в UTF-8.

Comment: Задавайте вопрос -- как настроить локаль в винде, наверняка кто-нибудь посоветует... (или используйте обычный побайтовый ввод-вывод и пишете перекодировки сами)

Comment: Т.е. формально код написан правильно, но проблема в кодировке?

Comment: Не уверен, что смешивать побайтовый (`puts`) и wide (`fwprintf` и т.п.) правильно (по крайней мере в Ubuntu это не работает)

Comment: Меня крайне смущает тот факт, что если во время выполнения цикла for выводить значения _check или _checkNext - то ничего не будет происходить. Как будто не правильно присваиваю символ из строки.

Comment: А чем выводите?

Comment: Выводил простым printf. Только сейчас понял, что, наверное, так не надо.
Не подскажете функцию вывода для unicode?

Comment: Попробуйте `wprintf`, попробуйте печатать сами коды (`%d`) (и уберите `puts` в начале)

Comment: Решил использовать `wprintf(L"%d\n", _check);`

Comment: Если использовать без `L`, то ничего не выведет. а `puts` я убрал

Comment: Ну, что-нибудь выводит? Для теста попробуйте константу типа `wchar_t` вывести. (вообще, я в винде не пишу)

Comment: Собственно, всё оказалось в разы проще.  Я использовал двойные кавычки, а надо было одинарные, вот, в итоге, ответ:   `if ((_check == L'Ж' && _checkNext == L'ы')..` и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответом на данный вопрос оказалось банально простое действие. Я использовал для сравнения символа двойные кавычки, вместо одинарных. Вот итоговый и рабочий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define LEN 1000

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    wprintf(L"'ЖИ' и 'ШИ' ПИШИ С БУКВОЙ 'И'!\n");

    wchar_t cArray[LEN];
    wchar_t _check = L' ', _checkNext = L' ';

    FILE *_initialFile, *_correctedFile;

    _wfopen_s(&_initialFile, L"initial.html", L"r,ccs=UNICODE");
    _wfopen_s(&_correctedFile, L"corrected.html", L"w,ccs=UNICODE");

    if (_initialFile == NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"Исходный файл пуст!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (fgetws(cArray, LEN, _initialFile) != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < wcslen(cArray); i++) {
            _check = cArray[i];
            _checkNext = cArray[i + 1];
            if ((_check == L'Ж' && _checkNext == L'ы') || (_check == L'ж' && _checkNext == L'ы') || (_check == L'Ш' && _checkNext == L'ы') || (_check == L'ш' && _checkNext == L'ы')) {
                cArray[i + 1] = L'и';
                i = i + 2;
            }
        }
        fwprintf_s(_correctedFile, L"%s", cArray);
    }

    fclose(_correctedFile);
    fclose(_initialFile);
    getchar();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```